# C++ Redistributable 14 conflict with VS2017 C++ Redistributable

Tags: visual-studio, vcredist

I rebuilt a laptop and in the process installed VS2017 which includes an install of C++ 2017 Redistributable(x64) - 14.10.24728

I have tried installing other apps that use C++ Redist 14 and they fail with the error message:

> "Another version of this product is already installed. Installation of
>    this version cannot continue. To configure or remove the existing
>    version of this product, use Add/Remove Programs on the Control Panel.
>    "
>
> The following components failed to install:
>   - Visual C++ "14" Runtime Libraries (x64)

I've tried installing C++ Redist (x64) - 14.0.23026 but get error message "Another version of this product is already installed etc."

Is there any way to resolve this without uninstalling VS2017 and reverting to VS2015?

PS: can someone with sufficient rights add 'visual-studio 2017' to tags list?

Comment: tried asking in [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/) yet..? i think this question is better to move there. also i don't think that **vcredist** should conflicting each other with different version -- have you take a look on Control Panel's **Program and Features**?

Comment: You would think they wouldn't conflict, but they do.  Probably because they are both version 14?  It was in Program and Features that I got the name of the VS2017 redist.

Comment: was this resolved?

Comment: No, it was not. However am setting up a new machine with current release of VS2017 and will see if issue remains.

Answer (score 0):

The VC++ 2017 redistributables REPLACE the VC++ redistributables. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49927822/3063884) for more details on how this can be checked programatically.

If you just need a program to use the VC++ 2015 redistributables, and the VC_++ 2017 redistributables are installed, given that it's an upgrade, the program requiring the 2015 version should work with the 2017 version.