# How to handle Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2017, vcredist

First of all, why can't I download it from Microsoft like before?

Second, when I install vcredist 2017 it will replace vcredist 2015(it's removed from "Add or remove program" list), is it fully backward compatible? Version is changed from 14.0.x.x to 14.10.x.x.

[C++ Redistributable 14 conflict with VS2017 C++ Redistributable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41586447/c-redistributable-14-conflict-with-vs2017-c-redistributable)

Comment: This is a thread showing where to download the redistributables for Visual Studio 2017:     https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/cae0b8ed-3287-4340-8373-d68888ae7c98/where-can-i-find-vs-2017s-runtime-redistributable?forum=vcgeneral

Comment: From [developercommunity](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/solutions/15740/view.html): "_The Visual C++ 2017 RC Redistributable is a binary-compatible in-place upgrade of the Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable and shares the same registry keys._"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks @edtheprogrammerguy

Solution from the link:
*I found them at : https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/
by clicking "Expand All",
at the bottom of the page*

Comment: This solution no longer applies for Visual Studio 2017 since it shows current downloads for Visual Studio which is at this date, July 2020, Visual Studio 2019. I expect as new versions of Visual Studio come available, this page will always show the most current version of Visual Studio and not a specific version such as Visual Studio 2017.